# Security fix for window.location.href

Tags: javascript, security, window.location, fortify, encoder

I have the below js code

```
var a = window.location.href.substring(0,window.location.href.lastIndex('/')+1) + "logout.jsp";

setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.href = a;
},1000);
```

When I am running a fortify scan for the above file, it is showing a security risk on the above line with Dynamic Code Evaluation :Code Injection.
Now I am not able to understand on how to fix it. Do I need to add any encoder for window.href or how to resolve this.
Also if we have encode , what I need to do.

Comment: I can't really see how this can be exploited to inject arbitrary code since `location.href` is generated by your server (unless certain parts of the URL is from arbitrary user input.) However, your code can be reduced to just `location.href = "logout.jsp"` which does the same thing.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 In this case I too can't see how injection can happen. But someone can push JS after `#` in the URL, which might create issues if not handled properly. So probably the tool is reporting false positives every time it sees `window.location.href` being manipulated.

Comment: Does your Javascript code reside directly in HTML page or in a separate js file ?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  I didn't understand how to reduce it to just  location.href='logout.jsp' work. Pardon me for my less knowledge.

Comment: @NisargShah  So what shall I do for it ? Shall I ask to supress?

Comment: I don't know well `fortify`, but maybe the issue it's finding is about `var a` defined outside the function in a general scope... try just moving the definition of `a` in the function. Normally you shouldn't need any encoder there

Comment: @BenjaminKeller In a separate js file

Comment: @pallabidas See *Nisarg Shah*'s answer below. You can avoid all the string manipulations by letting the browser handling it.

Comment: @pallabidas Setting `location.href='logout.jsp'` will tell the browser to replace the page name from something like "abc.jsp" to "logout.asp", and remove the querystring (and hash). Which seems like what your code is doing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the logic correctly, you are trying to get the path of the url without the page name, and then you intend to redirect to it.

If that is correct, you might be able to get it to work using,

```
var a = "logout.jsp";

setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.href = a;
},1000);
```

It should in principal get rid of the vulnerability, but I am not fully sure if the tool detects any other vulnerability in it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following link... maybe it could help you:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/151806/jquery-js-dynamic-code-evaluation-code-injection-on-settimeout-line

> **It's a false positive.**
>
> Reporting false code injection vulnerabilities is a well-known problem
>   with HP Fortify and [has confused developers before](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/code-injection-in-jquery-files). Fortify just
>   does basic static analysis of the Javascript code and can't go
>   arbitrarily deep to understand how it works. As @AlexanderOMara
>   suggested, it just seems to discover the *potentially* dangerous
>   `setTimeout()` function which can, as `setInterval()`, take a string
>   argument that would be executed as code, just like `eval()` does. This
>   the sort of vulnerability, the tool aims to discover:
>
> ```
> setTimeout('alert(' + document.location.hash.split('#')[1] + ')', 0);
> ```
>
> But in your case there is no user-supplied, unfiltered input to the
>   `setTimeout()` function and it therefore looks safe. Leaving you with
>   a great conclusion from the linked thread:
>
> > My advice is to stop running HP fortify reports. 
> >     Or pay the five thousand, or whatever  dollars to go to their classes so you could actually understand their malarkey.

Answered by [Arminius](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/95381/arminius).